# Find $f(x) $ given that: $f'(x)=\frac{f(x)-x}{f(x)+x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

> Find $f(x)$ given that:
>
> $f \colon \mathbb{R^+} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R^+}$, $f$ is differentiable function, and $f'(x)=\frac{f(x)-x}{f(x)+x}$

I tried  but couldn't get it that way.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $f(x)f'(x)+xf(x)-f(x)+x=0$, using Integration by parts

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Young $ x f^{'}(x) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'=\frac{y-x}{y+x}\\y'=\frac{\frac{y}{x}-1}{\frac{y}{x}+1}\\$$now use this substitution $A=\frac{y}{x}$ $$y=Ax\\y'=A'x+A\\A'x+A=\frac{A-1}{A+1}$$now solve for A then find y

Comment: It is a separable differential equation...

Comment: Arg! Yes, of course, silly me :-)

Comment: I get an implicit function $\;y^2+x^2=C=$ a constant. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't think so , $$y^2+x^2=c\\y'=-\frac{2x}{2y}$$