# A homogeneous differential equation. Solving by substitution: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-x}{y+x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think i'm stuck on this differential equation. I have a differential equation:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-x}{y+x}$

I need to find the implicit general solution. This is what I've done so far:

$dy(y+x) = dx(y-x)$

divide both sides by $x$ until we have each $y$ divided by $x$

$dy(\frac{y}{x} + 1) = dx(\frac{y}{x} - 1)$

Let $y = ux$. Therefore $y' = u'x + u$
 and $u = \frac{y}{x}$

I now have:

$dy(u + 1) = dx(u - 1)$

Therefore,

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{u-1}{u+1}$

$u'x + u = \frac{u-1}{u+1}$

$\frac{du}{dx}x = \frac{u-1}{u+1} - u$

In order to make this seperable I decided to make the RHS into one fraction first:

$= \frac{(u-1) - u(u+1)}{u+1} = \frac{-u^2 - 1}{u+1} = -\frac{u^2 + 1}{u+1} = -\frac{1}{u+1}(u^2 + 1)$

$\frac{dx}{xdu} = -(u+1)(\frac{1}{u^2 + 1})$

$\frac{dx}{x} = -(u+1)(\frac{1}{u^2 + 1})du$

Now integrate both sides and get:

$ln(x) + c = ...$

Now For RHS: $-\int(u+1)(\frac{1}{u^2 + 1}) du$

Using integration by parts, let $a = u+1, b' = \frac{1}{u^2 + 1}$

Where: $\int ab' = ab - \int bda$

We have $b = arctan(u), a' = 1$

RHS = $uarctan(u) + arctan(u) - \int arctan(u)$

$=uarctan(u) + arctan(u) - (uarctan(u) - \frac{1}{2}ln|u^2 + 1|)$

RHS = $arctan(u) + \frac{1}{2}ln|u^2 + 1|$

Therefore the solution to our differential equation in terms of $u$ is:

$ln(x) + C = arctan(u) + \frac{1}{2}ln|u^2 + 1|$

Substituting back in, the implicit solution is:

$ln(x) + C = arctan(\frac{y}{x}) + \frac{1}{2}ln|\frac{y^2}{x^2} + 1|$

Yet in my answer book the answer is

$ln(x^2 + y^2) + 2arctan(\frac{y}{x}) = c$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: your answer is corect too

Comment: The two solutions are indeed the same. Multiply by 2 and use the properties of the ln : 2ln x = ln x^2 and ln a/b = ln a- ln b but in your solution you assume x>0.

Comment: See also about this same ODE [Find $f(x) $ given that: $f'(x)=\frac{f(x)-x}{f(x)+x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1228203/115115), [Find the particular solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{y-x}{y+x}$ when $f(7)=7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2699834/115115), [Is there only one possible solution to homogenous DE's?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2140135/115115).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a negative sign on the right hand side.

Your RHS should have been $$RHS =  -arctan(u) - \frac{1}{2}ln|u^2 + 1|$$

That will take care of the difference between your answer and the book's anwwer.

Comment: Very true thank you!

Comment: @AndrewKor  Thank you for your attention and understanding.